# opencv and imutils are not working correctly in my docker

Tags: python, docker, opencv, anaconda, imutils

I need to install some libraries in an anaconda docker environment. Below are my dockerfile and environment.yml.
I can build my docker without error but when I run my code it seems opencv and imutils not correctly installed. anyone can tell me what should I do???

**dockerfile**

```
FROM continuumio/anaconda3
WORKDIR /app
#create environment
COPY environment.yml
RUN conda env create -f environment.yml
#make run commands use the new env
SHELL ["conda", "run", "-n", "myenv", "/bin/bash", "-c"] 
#make sure the env is activate
RUN echo "make sure anaconda activate"
RUN python -c "import dlib"
COPY app.py .
ENTRYPOINT ["conda", "run", "-n", "myenv", "python", "app.py"]
```

**environment.yml**

```
name: myenv
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.8.5
  - dlib
  - pymongo
  - requests
  - face_recognition
  - opencv
  - imutils
```

Comment: You will need to post a code example of it "not working". https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Typical advice is to not use a virtual environment in Docker, since the Docker image is an isolation environment in and of itself.  Can you `pip install` those packages on a plain `python` image, without trying to involve Anaconda?  (That would remove the need for the `SHELL` line and the complex `ENTRYPOINT`.)

Answer (score 0):

this my solution in case somebody has the same problem.
I have 2 issues:
1- I should install imutils with pip in anaconda
2- opencv did not work correctly because I need to install libglu too
so I just change my environment.yml file like below:

name: myenv
channels:

- conda-forge
- defaults
- anaconda

dependencies:

- python=3.8.5
- libglu
- dlib
- pymongo
- requests
- face_recognition
- opencv
- pip
- pip:

  - imutils